# SQL - How to get latest price based on effective date?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Fairly straight forward query that is eluding me.. how do I get the effective cost for each product based upon the latest effective date given 7-6-2020 as the effective date?

Price Table:

```
id  | product_name  | cost   | effective_date 
=======================================================
1   | Product A     | 8.00   | 1-5-2020
1   | Product A     | 9.50   | 1-6-2020
1   | Product A     | 10.00  | 1-7-2020
2   | Product B     | 4.00   | 5-6-2020
2   | Product B     | 4.50   | 5-7-2020
```

Expected Result:

```
id    | product_name  | cost   | effective_date 
-----------------------------------------------
1     | Product A     | 10.00   | 1-7-2020     
2     | Product B     | 4.00    | 5-6-2020
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, Postgres...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.effective_date = (select max(t2.effective_date)
                          from t t2
                          where t2.id = t.id and
                                t2.effective_date <= '2020-07-06'
                         );
```